# How to pass jessionid in cookies using httpclient in java

Tags: java, http, cookies, jsessionid

I get the jsessionid value from the server and try to pass the value in the cookie to avoid creation of multiple sessions for each request that is made

I use the below code to set the cookie value and add it to the context but it always gives me a 401 Authentication error no matter whatever additional parameters I add to the cookie

```
  HttpClientContext  localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
  BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();    
  BasicClientCookie cookie =   new BasicClientCookie("JSESSIONID", sessionID);
  cookie.setDomain("www.example.com");
  cookie.setPath("/");
  cookie.setVersion(0);             
  cookie.setAttribute("JSESSIONID", sessionID);            
  cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);                
  localContext.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
  localContext.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
  response = httpClient.execute(get,localContext);
```

Also the httpclient that I am using is the CloseableHttpClient

Please suggest any other workarounds or correct me if I do something wrong in the above code

Thanks in advance